# changedetection onPush for Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I have no experience with the Angular changeDetection. Now i want to change it from default to onPush. Maybe somebody can help me with my code.

I have a mat-table and a mongodb datasource. As soon as i change the changedetection, when I edit my data in my application, Angular is not triggered anymore, to update the data automatically. I don't know how i can trigger Angular to do so.

Thanks in Advance. Here is my Code from the ts-file where i display the data:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-merkmal',
  templateUrl: './merkmal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./merkmal.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MerkmalComponent implements OnInit {

  resultsLength = 0;
  isLoadingResults = true;
  appState$: Observable<AppState<CustomResponse<Merkmal>>>;
  readonly DataState = DataState;
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<CustomResponse<Merkmal>>(null);
  private isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoading$ = this.isLoading.asObservable();
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'wert', 'rubrik',
    'datentyp', 'werteliste', 'creationDate', 'actions'];

  data: Merkmal[] = [];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private merkmaleService: MerkmalService,
              public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMerkmale();
  }

  getMerkmale(): void {
    this.appState$ = this.merkmaleService.merkmale$
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          this.dataSubject.next(response);
          return {
            dataState: DataState.LOADED_STATE,
            appData: {...response, data: {objects: response.data.objects.reverse()}}
          }
        }),
    startWith({dataState: DataState.LOADING_STATE}),
        catchError((error: string) => {
          return of({dataState: DataState.ERROR_STATE, error})
        })
      )
  }
```

here is the ts-file from my edit-data-component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'edit-merkmal-form',
  templateUrl: './edit-merkmal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-merkmal.component.scss'],
  providers: [],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class EditMerkmalComponent implements OnInit {

  appState$: Observable<AppState<CustomResponse<Merkmal>>>;
  readonly DataState = DataState;
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<CustomResponse<Merkmal>>(null);
  private isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoading$ = this.isLoading.asObservable();
  submitted = false;
  isAddListenwerteVisible: boolean = false

  //html form group
  merkmalForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    wert: [''],
    datentyp: ['', Validators.required],
    sparte: ['', Validators.required],
    produktart: [''],
    rubrik: ['', Validators.required],
    werttyp: [''],
    listenwerte: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')])
  })

  merkmal: Merkmal = {
    createdBy: "PRODUCTS-DB",
    creationDate: undefined,
    datentyp: undefined,
    sparte: Sparte.KV,
    id: "0",
    produktart: "KV",
    rubrik: RubrikEnum.BASIS,
    version: undefined,
    agent: undefined,
    werteliste: [],
    name: '',
    wert: '',
    position: undefined
  };

  datentyp = DatentypEnum;
  datenTypes = [];

  dialogTitle: string
  private errorMessage: any;
  rubriken = RubrikEnum;
  rubriks= [];

  constructor(private merkmalService: MerkmalService,
              private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditMerkmalComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) {
                id, name, wert,
                datentyp, produktart, rubrik, sparte,
                werteliste, createdBy, creationDate,
                agent, version
              }: Merkmal) {


    this.datenTypes = Object.values(this.datentyp)
    if (id) {
      this.merkmal.id = id
      this.dialogTitle = name + " bearbeiten"
      this.merkmal.name = name
      this.merkmal.wert = wert
      this.merkmal.datentyp = datentyp
      this.merkmal.sparte = sparte
      this.merkmal.produktart = produktart
      this.merkmal.werteliste = werteliste
      this.merkmal.rubrik = rubrik
      this.merkmal.createdBy = createdBy
      this.merkmal.creationDate = creationDate
      this.merkmal.agent = agent
      this.merkmal.version = version
      this.isAddListenwerteVisible = datentyp == DatentypEnum.LISTE
      this.putFormData()
    } else {
      this.dialogTitle = "Merkmal anlegen"
      this.merkmal.id = null
      this.merkmal.name = ''
      this.merkmal.wert = ''
      this.merkmal.rubrik = RubrikEnum.BASIS
      this.merkmal.sparte = Sparte.KV
      this.merkmal.datentyp = datentyp
      this.merkmal.produktart = produktart
      this.merkmal.werteliste = werteliste
      this.merkmal.createdBy = null
      this.merkmal.creationDate = null
      this.merkmal.agent = null
      this.merkmal.version = null
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rubriks = Object.keys(this.rubriken)
  }

  save(): void {
    console.log("saving merkmal: " + this.merkmal)
    if (this.merkmalForm.valid) {
      if (this.merkmalForm.dirty) {
        const merkmalToSave = {...this.merkmal, ...this.merkmalForm.value};
        if (merkmalToSave.id === null || merkmalToSave.id === "0") {
          this.merkmalService.save$(merkmalToSave)
          .subscribe({
            next: (r) => this.onSaveComplete(r, "saved"),
            error: err => this.errorMessage = err
          });
        } else {
          this.merkmalService.update$(merkmalToSave)
          .subscribe({
            next: (r) => this.onSaveComplete(r, "updated"),
            error: err => this.errorMessage = err
          });
        }
      } else {
        this.onSaveComplete(null, "unknown");
      }

    } else {
      this.errorMessage = "Der Eintrag konnte nicht gespeichert werden!"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than answering on your code, let me answer on the principles.

Angular triggers change detection a lot of time when the default strategy is used. But when you use onPush strategy, only a few handful of actions trigger it. This includes (not exhaustive)

- Async pipe
- Using the change detector ref
- Inputs / Outputs
- Users actions (click, focus)

Using subjects and behavior subjects is a good way of increasing the performances of your application when using onPush strategy, with minimal changes required.

But it implies that you do it properly.

The most common mistake is memory reference assignement : to counter that, simply declare your observables as `readonly`.

The second most common mistake is to subscribe in your component, to assign a variable in the `subscribe` : in that case, your subscription should always contain a `detectChanges` call. Otherwise, you should instead declare your observables as a series of pipe-able operators.

So, the main goals are : `readonly` on your observables, and no `subscribe` in your TS code (or `detectChanges` in every subscription)

Once you have done that and mastered the new strategy, you can go back to code the old way !